# How to strongly type a simple rule engine class using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to build a simple rule engine class in Typescript that has two class methods: `addRule` and `execute`:

```
type Rule = {
  name: string;
  rule: (input: unknown) => number;
}

class RuleEngine {
  private rules: Rule[] = [];

  addRule(name: string, rule: (input: unknown) => number) {
    this.rules.push({ name, rule });
  }

  execute(initialInput: number) {
    return this.rules.reduce(
      (result, rule) => {
        result[rule.name] = rule.rule(result);
        return result;
      },
      { initialInput },
    );
  }
}
```

The result is an object with keys that are the names of the rules that have been added. So for example:

```
const engine = new RuleEngine();

engine.addRule("ruleOne", input => input.initialInput * 2);
engine.addRule("ruleTwo", input => input.initialInput + input.ruleOne);

const result = engine.execute(10);
// result = {
//   input: 10,
//   ruleOne: 20,
//   ruleTwo: 30,
// }
```

I've been breaking my brain for the past hours trying to figure out how to use Typescript in such a way that the input for any given function is strongly typed based on the rules that were added before. So in the above case, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
// input = { initialInput: number }
engine.addRule("ruleOne", input => input.initialInput * 2); 

// input = { initialInput: number, ruleOne: number }
engine.addRule("ruleTwo", input => input.initialInput + input.ruleOne);
```

Additionally, I want `result` to be strongly typed as well:

```
// result = { input: number, ruleOne: number, ruleTwo: number }
const result = engine.execute(10);
```

I've tried using generic in different ways, as well as overloads. But with overloads I had to manually write out an overload for the number of arguments which is tedious and felt like it could be simplified. Am I over-engineering this? I know that this is essentially a pipe operator, but I like the idea of adding these rules with a name, because there will potentially be a lot of them so I need a way to describe what each function does using the name.

Comment: the rules should store as part of type of `engine`. However, the type of an object can not be change by just call a method, you will need to re-create a new object with new type includes the original one and the rule. try to dig `zod` library to see how it extends exist schemas

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m0YRoW) meet your needs? (Please test against use cases you care about.) If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ah, I was also trying to make `asserts` work. Anyways, I think you should also consider the builder pattern: https://tsplay.dev/NdEKYm

Comment: @jcalz yes! It seems to be doing exactly what I want it to do, and my tests are passing with this improved version too. Thanks a lot, would love to understand better why it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `engine.addRule()` to have an effect on the *type* of `engine`, then the only possible way that could happen in TypeScript is if the `addRule` is [an *assertion method*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) with a return type of the form `asserts this is ⋯`.  And this has some constraints which might make your life unpleasant... one is that you need to explicitly [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `engine`, since assertion functions or methods only behave as advertised if they have annotations:

```
const sadEngine = new RuleEngine();
sadEngine.addRule("ruleOne", i => i.initialInput); // error!
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Assertions require every name in the call target 
// to be declared with an explicit type annotation.

const happyEngine: RuleEngine = new RuleEngine();
// ------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <---- this annotation is necessary
happyEngine.addRule("ruleOne", i => i.initialInput); // okay
```

Another is that assertion functions only work if the operation can be seen as a *narrowing*.  That means every time you call `engine.addRule()`, the new type of `engine` must be a subtype of the old type.  That's pretty restrictive. In your example I've managed to do this, but such things can be fragile.  If your operation needs to arbitrarily mutate the type of `engine` in a non-narrowing way, then TypeScript can't really model that.

And finally, such narrowings only take place in a particular scope.  If you try to close over these with functions, you will get the issue as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) where the narrowings are reset.  The compiler can't be sure that something else hasn't happened before the function closing over the value is called:

```
const happyEngine: RuleEngine = new RuleEngine();
happyEngine.addRule("ruleOne", i => i.initialInput); // okay
const okay = happyEngine.execute(1);
/* const okay: {
    initialInput: number;
    ruleOne: number;
} */

function foo() {
  const oops = happyEngine.execute(1);
  /* const oops: {
    initialInput: number;
  } */
}
```

To work around all of these you can change your implementation so that the method returns a value of the new type.  So instead of

```
engine.addRule(⋯);
engine.addRule(⋯);
engine.addRule(⋯);
const r = engine.execute(⋯);
```

You'd write

```
const e1 = engine.addRule(⋯);
const e2 = e1.addRule(⋯);
const e3 = e2.addRule(⋯);
const r = e3.execute(⋯);
```

Or even

```
const r = engine.addRule(⋯).addRule(⋯).addRule(⋯).execute(⋯);
```

But such a refactoring is outside of the scope of the question as asked (or at least I'm not going to go into that).

---

So here's one way to do it with assertion methods:

```
class RuleEngine<K extends string = "initialInput">  {

  private rules: any[] = []

  addRule<L extends string>(
    name: L,
    rule: (input: { [P in K]: number }) => number
  ): asserts this is RuleEngine<K | L> {
    this.rules.push({ name, rule });
  }

  execute(initialInput: number): { [P in K]: number } {
    return this.rules.reduce(
      (result, rule) => {
        result[rule.name] = rule.rule(result);
        return result;
      },
      { initialInput },
    );
  }
}
```

Here `RuleEngine` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `K`, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of keys in output of `execute()`, and I've made it [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `"initialInput"`, since that's how we want a `RuleEngine` to behave at the beginning.  So the input/output type will be `{ [P in K]: number }`, which is equivalent to `Record<K, number>` using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).

The `rules` property I've given the "fuzzy" type of an array of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) since I don't want to worry about the impossible task of convincing the compiler that the rules will always be of the right type. And I don't want the `rules` to get in the way of potential narrowing.

And `addRules()` is itself generic in `L`, the type of the `name` parameter.  And the `rule` parameter is a callback that takes an `input` of type `{[P in K]: number}` and returns a `number`.  And finally, the return type is `asserts this is RuleEngine<K | L>`, adding `L` to the union.

Let's test it out:

```
const engine: RuleEngine = new RuleEngine();
engine; // const engine: RuleEngine<"initialInput">
engine.addRule("ruleOne", input => input.initialInput * 2);
engine; // const engine: RuleEngine<"initialInput" | "ruleOne">
engine.addRule("ruleTwo", input => input.initialInput + input.ruleOne);
engine; // const engine: RuleEngine<"initialInput" | "ruleOne" | "ruleTwo">
const result = engine.execute(10);
/* const result: {
    initialInput: number;
    ruleOne: number;
    ruleTwo: number;
} */
// result = {
//   input: 10,
//   ruleOne: 20,
//   ruleTwo: 30,
// }
```

Looks good!  Each line takes into account the state changes implied by the previous lines.

So there you go, an assertion method can give you the behavior you're looking for, with a bunch of caveats that might be deal-breakers, depending on your actual use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ijxRWzn2-PYABqU8w1A1lD9otDs0j5NFyfq6fZu5z-OLpW2iPpwgG7vuBbvmO7JjhwA7FuQFxXH4ACMAAMJrdlBIKYhyaTArOeZPH8DSMFyRLAfgzykeRcTaHusrUa8xwVLAnbGsA8YwZY8jxjIDapLA6ExHxewPlRvZoSJZp0agDH6AAzFJnFmjKcqjl4dgavgWooLq6badcjJQFpRYbmWqDbpRKCHjgTY4Oef5ERQRxxmaZSMLKjAAIQqbAToBQ6fkAIIwO0-oKiCACOiA4PCpAqGURjBGEKBfO6aUgAIYBzGGWCgrAfkULKsClLANAXJA8I0LA2q8F0BjfOQIhgDgIC8HMRgiGlXo+n68oLAo2FdBAIgiEYhlfhmmocDqeqGUaxzxtaK1WnagWOi6bpQo13q+nwAb9MGOgmeGwAjWNE1maWW5AeJNn1vZjm5h2LmvrAsoANYQBG2FfT9lgXeNhkLIhlxUKhmEJkmY7-UY+GzIRr1MWUtFiSgj4o2R0psRxwAAGaIBgIAHd8+OyrKRpAjIf2yiIcAcEDV3rmDyEoZKcZYTDH103o1NBEj85Y+RrHsdKQA)

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you so much for your help and the very elaborate explanation!